# Looking for manga apps which filter out mature content

Tags: resources

My son is into manga and anime. When I look for 'kid-friendly' sources for him to read and watch, I make sure that they filter out the mature stuffs. Currently, he has the Crunchy Roll app, and it seems to be pretty kid-friendly and filtered. If I am wrong, please let me know.

He asked me to check out an app called "Manga Rock", but from the first page, the results were not the kind of stuff I want him to read due to the heavily mature content. (If you know what I mean...)

Any recommendations for a manga app that I can feel comfortable with?

Comment: 1st problem - age-appropriate perception of content is quite different in Japan.  That is, whatever is targeted/considered fine for your son's age range in Japan probably doesn't match what's in the US/you want.  I don't know if the CR app has a filter on it...

Comment: I'm not sure if it has an age filter, but I checked out the Viz app for Android a while ago, and everything on there looked pretty PG-13. They have all the popular stuff like Naruto, One Piece, Death Note, etc.

Answer (score 2):

CrunchyRoll also has a manga app for [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.crunchyroll.crmanga) and [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/manga-by-crunchyroll/id617048063?mt=8). You can also view their manga selection on their main site.

You can set a filter to block mature content in your profile settings. Unfortunately, you can't password protect this from change, so if your son found that the filter was on, he could potentially turn it off.

Access to manga is exclusively for paying members.